# Translating a SQL query to a Django view, triple inner join

Tags: python, sql, django

I have this models.py

```
class Download(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
song = models.ForeignKey(Song)
download_date = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add=True)

class Song(models.Model):
file_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I want to build a query to know how many downloads have the songs of all users. I am planning to show it like: User45 (56 downloads), User46 (44 downloads) and so on.

I can't group the downloads by users as it seems that a triple join is not working.

I have this:

```
var = Download.objects.filter(download_date__day=today.day, download_date__month=today.month, download_date__year=today.month).values('song', 'song__user', 'song__user__first_name', 'song__user__last_name').annotate(numer_downloads = Count('song__user')).order_by('-numer_downloads')
```

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off doing the filter on the Song class like so:

```
songs = Song.objects.annotate(download_count=Count('download_set')).all().order_by('-download_set')
```

Then in your template you'd do something like this:

```
{% for song in songs %}
    {{ song.user.username }} ({{ song.download_count }})
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: 1. What is download_set?  2. I really appreciate the time of checking my question but I do need the query to show total downloads by song uploader (user). Thanks a lot.

Comment: ```download_set``` would be the default reverse look-up name for that field. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects